# Prevent me from submitting answers which are just the question's template

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Case in point:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317441/4532996

[Open Source Advertising - 1H 2016](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314722) is a question that provides an answer  template -- when you scroll to the bottom, there's a answer template waiting to be filled in.

In this case, the template is:

```
[![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

  [1]: https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/ad-placeholder.png
  [2]: http://clickthrough-url
```

Clicking "Submit Answer" without modifying the template gets you:

[image]

No way is that something that should ever happen. Perhaps adding a check on whether there's any output rendered from the Markdown after links have been resolved, or just compare the answer with the template?

Comment: But the answer isn't blank. It is empty, visually, but there's an image + a non-existing URL in the HTML.

Comment: @Werner but why am I allowed to submit the exact unmodified template as an answer? the template is there to be modified, right?

Comment: So would changing (say) `Tagline` to `Tag-line` be change? If so, there would still be no visual change without using the mouse-over. Also, [the image exists](https://cdn.sstatic.net/img/ad-placeholder.png).

Comment: @Werner I don't know, `edits must be at least 6 characters`? That's not my point, that's the devs' decision

Comment: @Werner well, that's odd

Comment: @Werner maybe check if the rendered markdown after resolving links (i.e. the preview humans see) isn't none?

Comment: You realize that there is only a single post on every graduated site's Meta that actually has a template attached to it? That's an incredibly small use-case. A much simpler solution than changing the code to detect this is to just delete the answer if someone actually just posts the template.

Comment: @animuson no, I didn't know that at all and the fact it's exactly one post doesn't make any sense to me but fair enough

Comment: @cat This was a tiny workaround that was implemented specifically for the community ads posts. Templates do not exist in any fashion anywhere else on the network. If they ever do, we will likely implement this feature along with it (eg when voting to close it doesn't let you submit the default text in a custom off-topic reason), but for now it's not particularly worth the time. There's only one of these open per site at a time, and disallowing it doesn't really achieve anything in the long-run.

Comment: @animuson well, thank you for the information. I guess this should be closed as off-topic and [tag:status-declined] or [tag:status-bydesign]